# Диалоги как у вконтакте. Как прилепить блок ввода сообщения к низу блока чата?

Tags: html, css, css3, flexbox

Верстаю диалоги примерно как у вк. Использую flexbox

Скрин

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Код

```css
.block-flex-div { display: flex;width: 100%;justify-content: space-between;box-sizing: border-box;} 
  .block-line-flex {display: flex;padding: 8px; height: auto;font-size: 14px;width: 100%;color: #666;font-weight: 500;text-align: left;box-sizing: border-box; }
   .block-column-flex{ flex: 1;}  
   
   .block-flex-div.dialogs-block{height: 100%;}
    .block-column-flex.dialogs-user-list{flex: 1 1 13%; min-width:150px; white-space: nowrap;overflow:hidden;overflow-y:auto;color: #999;font-size:16px;border: 1px solid #efefef;}  
     .block-column-flex .dialogs-user-info{padding: 10px; border-top: 1px solid #efefef;text-align:left}  
      .block-column-flex .dialogs-user-info:first-child {border-top: 0px solid #efefef;}  
      .block-column-flex .dialogs-user-info:last-child {border-bottom: 1px solid #efefef;}  
      
      .block-column-flex .dialogs-user-info .dialogs-user-photo {flex: 1 1 20%;padding: 5px;}  
      .block-column-flex .dialogs-user-info .dialogs-user-name {flex: 2 1 80%;padding: 5px;}  
      
    .block-column-flex.dialogs-user-chat{flex: 2 1 80%;border-top: 1px solid #efefef;border-right: 1px solid #efefef;border-bottom: 1px solid #efefef;}  
    
    
    .block-line-flex.dialogs-user-chat-body-wrap {height: 90%;}
    .block-line-flex.dialogs-user-chat-input {background: #fafbfc; max-height:70px; border-top: 1px solid #efefef}
    
       .block-column-flex.chat-text-input {flex: 1 1 80%;padding:5px;}  
       .block-column-flex.chat-text-input #text {box-sizing: border-box; width: 100%;padding:8px 10px;}  
       .block-column-flex.chat-input-send-bottom {flex: 2 1 20%;padding:5px;}
```

```html
<div class="block-flex-div dialogs-block">
 <div class="block-column-flex dialogs-user-list">
      <div class="block-line-flex dialogs-user-info">
          <div class="block-column-flex dialogs-user-photo">
            <img src="http://cliparting.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/05/Smiley-face-crazy-face-clip-art-smiley-eyes-clip-art-vector-clip-art.jpg" width="50" class="img-circle img-responsive vknotify-comment-avatar">
          </div>
          <div class="block-column-flex dialogs-user-name">
            Имя 
          </div>
        </div>
      <div class="block-line-flex dialogs-user-info">
        <div class="block-column-flex dialogs-user-photo">
            <img src="http://cliparting.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/05/Smiley-face-crazy-face-clip-art-smiley-eyes-clip-art-vector-clip-art.jpg" width="50" class="img-circle img-responsive vknotify-comment-avatar">
          </div>
          <div class="block-column-flex dialogs-user-name">
            Имя 
          </div>
        </div>
      <div class="block-line-flex dialogs-user-info">
        <div class="block-column-flex dialogs-user-photo">
            <img src="http://cliparting.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/05/Smiley-face-crazy-face-clip-art-smiley-eyes-clip-art-vector-clip-art.jpg" width="50" class="img-circle img-responsive vknotify-comment-avatar">
          </div>
          <div class="block-column-flex dialogs-user-name">
            Имя 
          </div>
        </div>
      <div class="block-line-flex dialogs-user-info">
        <div class="block-column-flex dialogs-user-photo">
            <img src="http://cliparting.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/05/Smiley-face-crazy-face-clip-art-smiley-eyes-clip-art-vector-clip-art.jpg" width="50" class="img-circle img-responsive vknotify-comment-avatar">
          </div>
          <div class="block-column-flex dialogs-user-name">
            Имя 
          </div>
        </div>
      <div class="block-line-flex dialogs-user-info">
        <div class="block-column-flex dialogs-user-photo">
            <img src="http://cliparting.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/05/Smiley-face-crazy-face-clip-art-smiley-eyes-clip-art-vector-clip-art.jpg" width="50" class="img-circle img-responsive vknotify-comment-avatar">
          </div>
          <div class="block-column-flex dialogs-user-name">
            Имя 
          </div>
        </div>

  
  </div>
 <div class="block-column-flex dialogs-user-chat">
  
  <div class="block-line-flex dialogs-user-chat-body-wrap">
 чат
  </div>
  <div class="block-line-flex dialogs-user-chat-input">
   <div class="block-column-flex chat-text-input">
    <input type="text" id="text" name="text" value="" placeholder="Текст ответа"> 
   </div>
   <div class="block-column-flex chat-input-send-bottom">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-success">Отправить</button>
   </div>
  </div>
  
 </div>
</div>
```

Как мне блок `.dialogs-user-chat-input` прижать к низу блока `.dialogs-user-chat`, а блок `.dialogs-user-chat-body-wrap` чтобы занимал все остальное пространство.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вам нужно сделать всю обертку флексбоксом, расположить элементы в колонку и окну чата добавить свойство `flex-grow: 1`.

```css
.block-flex-div {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  justify-content: space-between;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.block-line-flex {
  display: flex;
  padding: 8px;
  height: auto;
  font-size: 14px;
  width: 100%;
  color: #666;
  font-weight: 500;
  text-align: left;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.block-column-flex {
  flex: 1;
}

.block-flex-div.dialogs-block {
  height: 100%;
}

.block-column-flex.dialogs-user-list {
  flex: 1 1 13%;
  min-width: 150px;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  overflow-y: auto;
  color: #999;
  font-size: 16px;
  border: 1px solid #efefef;
}

.block-column-flex .dialogs-user-info {
  padding: 10px;
  border-top: 1px solid #efefef;
  text-align: left
}

.block-column-flex .dialogs-user-info:first-child {
  border-top: 0px solid #efefef;
}

.block-column-flex .dialogs-user-info:last-child {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #efefef;
}

.block-column-flex .dialogs-user-info .dialogs-user-photo {
  flex: 1 1 20%;
  padding: 5px;
}

.block-column-flex .dialogs-user-info .dialogs-user-name {
  flex: 2 1 80%;
  padding: 5px;
}

.block-column-flex.dialogs-user-chat {
  flex: 2 1 80%;
  border-top: 1px solid #efefef;
  border-right: 1px solid #efefef;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #efefef;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.block-line-flex.dialogs-user-chat-body-wrap {
  flex-grow: 1;
}

.block-line-flex.dialogs-user-chat-input {
  background: #fafbfc;
  max-height: 70px;
  border-top: 1px solid #efefef
}

.block-column-flex.chat-text-input {
  flex: 1 1 80%;
  padding: 5px;
}

.block-column-flex.chat-text-input #text {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 8px 10px;
}

.block-column-flex.chat-input-send-bottom {
  flex: 2 1 20%;
  padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="block-flex-div dialogs-block">
  <div class="block-column-flex dialogs-user-list">
    <div class="block-line-flex dialogs-user-info">
      <div class="block-column-flex dialogs-user-photo">
        <img src="http://cliparting.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/05/Smiley-face-crazy-face-clip-art-smiley-eyes-clip-art-vector-clip-art.jpg" width="50" class="img-circle img-responsive vknotify-comment-avatar">
      </div>
      <div class="block-column-flex dialogs-user-name">
        Имя
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="block-line-flex dialogs-user-info">
      <div class="block-column-flex dialogs-user-photo">
        <img src="http://cliparting.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/05/Smiley-face-crazy-face-clip-art-smiley-eyes-clip-art-vector-clip-art.jpg" width="50" class="img-circle img-responsive vknotify-comment-avatar">
      </div>
      <div class="block-column-flex dialogs-user-name">
        Имя
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="block-line-flex dialogs-user-info">
      <div class="block-column-flex dialogs-user-photo">
        <img src="http://cliparting.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/05/Smiley-face-crazy-face-clip-art-smiley-eyes-clip-art-vector-clip-art.jpg" width="50" class="img-circle img-responsive vknotify-comment-avatar">
      </div>
      <div class="block-column-flex dialogs-user-name">
        Имя
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="block-line-flex dialogs-user-info">
      <div class="block-column-flex dialogs-user-photo">
        <img src="http://cliparting.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/05/Smiley-face-crazy-face-clip-art-smiley-eyes-clip-art-vector-clip-art.jpg" width="50" class="img-circle img-responsive vknotify-comment-avatar">
      </div>
      <div class="block-column-flex dialogs-user-name">
        Имя
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="block-line-flex dialogs-user-info">
      <div class="block-column-flex dialogs-user-photo">
        <img src="http://cliparting.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/05/Smiley-face-crazy-face-clip-art-smiley-eyes-clip-art-vector-clip-art.jpg" width="50" class="img-circle img-responsive vknotify-comment-avatar">
      </div>
      <div class="block-column-flex dialogs-user-name">
        Имя
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="block-column-flex dialogs-user-chat">
    <div class="block-line-flex dialogs-user-chat-body-wrap">
      чат
    </div>
    <div class="block-line-flex dialogs-user-chat-input">
      <div class="block-column-flex chat-text-input">
        <input type="text" id="text" name="text" value="" placeholder="Текст ответа">
      </div>
      <div class="block-column-flex chat-input-send-bottom">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-success">Отправить</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: супер! Спасибо, просто это свойство не знал.